# How to create Dockerfile for Spring Boot app?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, kubernetes

Hello Fellow Developers,

I am new to software development and looking forward to doing transitioning to software development.

I am learning new skills and tools to scale up and I came across DOCKER and KUBERNETES

I have completed my backend with spring boot, java and MYSQL I just wanted to know how to dockerize an image for the spring boot application in an industrial real-time manner just to get a hang of it.

Things to image

Environment: JAVA 17

Dependencies: POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.greatlearning.employeemanagementservice</groupId>
    <artifactId>employeemanagementservice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>employeemanagementservice</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- spring security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Application-properties:

```
server.port=8082
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/empdb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=*s12
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

This is an employee management project with simple CRUD operation I have done. It would be helpful if someone can guide me through Docker image settings.

Pardon me, If it is inappropriate to post such questions in a stack overflow.

Comment: can we build a separate container for web security configuration? If so, kindly help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the followoing Dockerfile. It performs a multi-stage build where in the first stage, your code is compiled to an executable. Then in the next stage, only the parts necessary for running your application are copied so that your Docker image has less size than if you copied all your uncompiled and compiled code in the Docker image. For more information about multi-stage builds, consult the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/) or one of the countless internet tutorials.

```
FROM maven:3.8-openjdk-17 as maven
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./pom.xml .
RUN mvn dependency:go-offline
COPY ./src ./src
RUN mvn package -DskipTests=true
WORKDIR /app/target/dependency
RUN jar -xf ../employeemanagementservice.jar

FROM ibm-semeru-runtimes:open-17-jre-centos7
ARG DEPENDENCY=/app/target/dependency
COPY --from=maven ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
COPY --from=maven ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF
COPY --from=maven ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app
CMD java -server -Xmx1024m -Xss1024k -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=135m -XX:CompressedClassSpaceSize=28m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=13m -XX:+IdleTuningGcOnIdle -Xtune:virtualized -cp app:app/lib/* com.greatlearning.employeemanagementservice.Application
```

I made the following assumptions:

1. Your build artifact is named `employeemanagementservice.jar`. Check your `target` directory after your maven build to verify. I always configure it like this in the pom.xml

```xml
 <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
 </build>
```

2. You run your tests in a CI/CD pipeline and don't want to run them in the Docker image build step. If you wanted to run your tests you'd have to remove the `-DskipTests=true` from the `RUN mvn package -DskipTests=true` command.
3. Your main class is called `Application` and it resides in the `com.greatlearning.employeemanagementservice` package. If not, change it in the Docker `CMD` command.
4. You want your service to use at most 1GB of RAM. If not, change the `-Xmx1024m` to your desired amount. The other `java` arguments are for optimization purposes, you can look them up online.

Comment: Thank you @Times, really appreciate your effort in helping me out and the documentation you shared was really helpful. Is it possible to create separate images for 'jre+jdk+pom' and spring boot application so that I can use the jre+jdk+pom for different application other than the current application that I am building.

Comment: Hi @VidyasagarRamachandran, you're welcome :) I don't really get your question, what do you mean by separate images for 'jre+jdk+pom'? You can reuse this Dockerfile for other applications as well, but you need to change the main class then.

Comment: sorry for making it difficult for you, I am in the learning stage, so what I have grasped/understood is that each docker file can be pushed to the hub and depending on the project we can run the command "docker build" of the image file and then use it for other similar application. Is it correct what I have understood? if so, we can do the same and push the jdk+pom configured Dockerfile to the hub and later on we can run the same in a different application right?

Comment: @VidyasagarRamachandran well, then you have misunderstood it gravely. I suggest that you look into the Docker documentation again. You have a Dockerfile which allows you to run `docker build` thereby creating an image. The image can then be pushed into Dockerhub. It's not the file that is pushed and you execute Docker build to create an image in the first place. The image can then be run like an executable when Docker is available on the target system.

Comment: Thank you so much @Times, I appreciate your effort (y) :)